# Why the stale connection check is not 100% reliable in apache httpclient connectionPool

Tags: java, tcp, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

In section `2.5. Connection eviction policy` of the documentation 
[connection managment doc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) for httpclient
mentions that

> HttpClient tries to mitigate the problem by testing whether the connection is 'stale', that is no longer valid because it was closed on the server side, prior to using the connection for executing an HTTP request. **The stale connection check is not 100% reliable.**

I am just wondering why stale connection cant be checked reliably ?
What logical/TCP construct dont allow it to happen reliably?

Comment: Stale connection test is done by periodically checking whether the connection is inactive for a long period of time. Obviously this means that some connections can be dead but still in use.

Comment: Becasue it is trying to predict the future.

Comment: @freakish what is the time period... a ref to code will help..

Comment: @Bhuvan you have the code in the link you've provided. The `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is trivial. There is always a window of time, however small, between the successful stale check and request execution, in which the opposite endpoint can close the connection on its end and make the connection stale on the client end.

Comment: so that the only logical construct that is preventing 100%reliable check.. there is no other logical/TCP construct that also contribute to "not 100% reliable" ?

Comment: @Bhuvan The stale connection check is nothing more than a short read operation. It is absolutely no different than any other read operation from the TCP standpoint.

Comment: @ok2c, do you have a link to the implementation? Is it simply a poll() with a small timeout over the socket?

Comment: @cspinetta https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/impl/io/BHttpConnectionBase.java#L291